# Remove newline character while XML parsing

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

I am facing a problem while XML parsing.
I have an NSMutablestring currentElementValue that has newlines into it. It has been received as an XMl from a web source.
Even when i am trying to remove newline charactersets of substring the first 3 char there is no effect on the string.

What can be done here?
Regards

PC

Code is

```
(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

 if(!currentElementValue) 
  currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
 else
 {
 [currentElementValue substringFromIndex:3];
 [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

 NSLog(@"Processing Value : %@ with length %d", currentElementValue,[currentElementValue length] );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` remove characters from the beginning and end of  string only.  The substring call in the previous line doesn't change anything.